# python sympy lambdify not working inside function

Tags: sympy, lambdify

I'm trying to write a function that has a literal function as a parameter:

```
def derive(x, y):
    x = symbols(x)
    y = symbols(y)
    return lambdify(x, y)    

derive(5, 'x**2')
```

This returns a syntax error:

```
  File "<lambdifygenerated-32>", line 1
    def _lambdifygenerated(25.0):
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I write (outside the function scope):

> f = lambdify(x, x**2)
> f(5)

it works.
I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?  Why do you call your function `derive`? Why do you think using `lambdify` would be useful in your approach? Writing something like `x = symbols(x)` is extremely confusing, and should be avoided; please don' t reuse the variable name there.

Comment: the reason i wanted to write a function in that way is this:
in machine learning, there are several steps for calculating a derivative of a given function (using pytorch). hence i wanted to create the above function (though incomplete) where one of its parameters is the function to be differentiated. For example, derive(5, x**2) would give 2*x=10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sympy you can get the derivative of a function via `diff()`. `.subs(x, 5)` fills in the value `5` for `x`. An example:

```py
from sympy.abc import x

f = x**2
print(f.diff(x).subs(x,5))
```

Here is how a function that would calculate the derivative of a given function at a given value could look like. `evalf()` can be used to iron out symbolic parts (such as giving a numeric approximation for `2*pi` or `Sqrt(5)` which sympy standard wants to keep in their exact symbolic form).

```py
def derive_and_evaluate(x, f, xval):
    return f.diff(x).subs(x, xval).evalf()

derive_and_evaluate(x, x**2, 5)
```

If you need the same derivative for a lot of x-values, you can do:

```
from sympy import lambdify

g = lambdify(x, f.diff(x)) # now `g` is a numpy function with one parameter
```

Or, if you want a function that does the derivation and converts to numpy form:

```py
def derive_and_lambdify(x, f):
    return lambdify(x, f.diff(x))

g = derive_and_lambdify(x, x**2)
print(g(5))
```

From then on, you can use `g` similar to other numpy functions. Here is a more elaborate example:

```py
from sympy import lambdify, sin
from sympy.abc import x

f = sin(1 / (1 + x ** 2))
g = lambdify(x, f.diff(x))

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xs = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
ys = g(xs)
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

[image: plotting the derivative]

Comment: Excellent. Much more valuable and appreciable info than required by the question. Thanks very much.

Comment: I can't see an option to 'accept answer' on stackoveflow.